# How to delete scene after moving to the next in Corona sdk?

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk

In composer library I used one scene, and then moved to the new, but the object (background) with the old scenes remained in place. What could be the problem? How to remove the scene after transition to a new one?

Comment: Do you add background to scene group (scene.view)?

Comment: @Idurniat, oh, I really forgot to add to the group. Now I made it through sceneGroup:insert(background).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new scene you can do

```
composer.removeScene("lastScene.lua")
```